# Is there a good guide on JDO?

Tags: jdo

i'm looking for a good guide for JDO (Java Data Objects) API. I tried to learn from DataNucleus site and have read the Oracle docs about it but i can't seem to connect the dots as to how JDO is used :S. So even thou it could be a dumb request, i will ask it anyway. Is there a comprehensive guide on JDO 2.3 or 3.0 with a sample app for an RDBMS ? If not can anyone make a simple sample app with JDO (standalone or WEB) so that i can grasp the concept of how i should implement JDO ?

Thanks.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/overview does that help

Comment: As far as i can tell, this google guide is for use of JDO with GAE. I'm looking to learn how to implement JDO for starters with an RDBMS like MySql or PostgreSql. I.ve been at this for days and i would prefer a good explaining guide or some sample app to see how JDO is implemented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataNucleus JDO has ample docs from what I see.
http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/jdo/api.html
and tutorial at http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/jdo/guides/tutorial_rdbms.html

Any web search would have found those

Comment: I have already found these tutorials on DataNucleus, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Those links provide many links from them which cover all topics, including a free JDO (1) book http://www.datanucleus.org/downloads/documents/jdo-robinroos-1.0.pdf

Comment: Thanks Neil for your answer.